# Vs Code will not autocomplete from a python file or library after appending the path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, autocomplete

Suppose I have two python files, `funcs.py` and `current.py` and that both of these files are inside the same directory. If I add `from funcs import *` inside `current.py` then VS Code will recognize all of the functions that I have in `funcs.py` and will also code complete for them.

For example, if within `funcs.py`, I have the following:

```
def some_function():
    # body of the function
```

then when I am working on `current.py`, VS Code will autocomplete `some_function` for me in the sense where if I start typing `some_f...` then `some_function` will be included in the list of suggestions that VS Code gives me.

Now suppose that `current.py` is inside `directory_1` and that `funcs.py` is inside `directory_2` and that inside `current.py` I add the following lines:

```
from sys import path
path.append(path_to_directory2)
```

Then if I am working within `current.py`, I can successfully import `funcs.py` and use the functions, but VS Code will now not autocomplete any of the functions imported from `funcs.py` like it did when both `current.py` and `funcs.py` were in the same directory.

Is there a way to have VS Code auto complete these functions if the two files are in different directories?

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I offer two answers.

1. If you want to get automatic completion without needing it to be run successfully. You can add `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": []` to your settings.json and specify the path manually.
2. If you want to run the code successfully without changing the original code. You can try `.env` file.

Firstly, create the `.env` file under your workspace.

Secondly, add `python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",` to your `settings.json`.

Thirdly, add the folder you need to import as an environment variable to the `.env` file. For example, `PYTHONPATH=C:/`.

Answer (score 0):

[this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete) works well for my path autocompletion in the past. Just tested your case and also works smoothly.